# AWS Lambda Triggering via SNS | Million Messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a use case in which my system will send almost 40 million messages to SNS in span of 8-10 hours. I have a subscription from SNS to Lambda.

My question is how will the scaling work in this case? I understand there is a concurrency limit per account depending upon region. My region has 1000 concurrency, that means at one point in time 1000 executions will happen in parallel. When I send more than 1000 messages in SNS, how will lambda behave in this case? Will the messages go in some internal aws lambda queue and they will be executed as and when lambda has capacity to do so? Please note that there is no requirement of making it process in near real time.

I couldn’t find anything like this in documentation. Really appreciate if someone can point to me the correct documentation or explain the behaviour in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Details of how lambda scales are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html). You lambda will be **throttled** if have more requests it can handle. You can **submit support ticket** to get lambda limits increased for your use case.

Comment: thanks @Marcin- That means it will execute everything but since it will be throttled, it will probably take more time. If i get the limit increased, it will finish all the run faster.

Comment: yes. with increased limit you will be able to have >1000 function invocations running at the same time.